# SQL Server Resource Governor on Single Database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, resource-governor

I have a database for a piece of proprietary software that resides on a SQL Server 2005 instance shared with some databases for C# apps I developed. I'm having an issue with some of the proprietary software's stored procedures eating up resources. Is there a way for me to limit the CPU usage of a particular database? I've advocated moving the DBs to a different server / instance, but I need a solution that can hold me off until then.

Answer (score 2):

You can use resource governor and have a function on it which guide system to a workload with database name , and then limit cpu and memory.

Comment: Is there any way you could provide a basic example? You may use any database name you see fit.

Comment: An example is you write a udf and check the dbname by DBNAME() system function , and if it was your desired database name the return the name of workload you want.
You can read more about it on :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: You may wish to use ORIGINAL_DB_NAME() instead. See: https://logicalread.com/sql-server-resource-governor-manage-io-mo01/#.XB07D3UvxhE